# Artifactory Replication by default \ setup once, copy to others

Tags: artifactory

I'm currently setting up my main instances of Jfrog Artifactory Enterprise Edition and I'd like to be able to just input repositories once and then by default, have it configured correctly on the second master instance for Event based replication and for pull replication on the edge nodes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you would like to set up some kind of DR where you would replicate the data from master1 to master2 and to do so you need to have the exact replica of repository configuration from master1 to master2. For now, you can set up all repositories in the master1 and then take the artifactory.config.latest.xml under the <JFrog_Home>/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory folder from master1 and import it in the master2 by copying the file into the master2's same location <JFrog_Home>/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory folder and change the name of the file from artifactory.config.latest.xml to artifactory.config.import.xml and restart the master2.

I would also recommend referring to the below articles,

1. [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/configuration-descriptor-files-what-they-are-and-how-theyre-used/)
2. [Wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuration+Files) on configuration files